# When filtering a Delphi TDataSet is there a difference between the NULL and BLANK keywords?

Tags: delphi, filter, tdataset

When using the Filter property of TDataSet I enter the following filters:

```
'State <> ''CA'' or State = BLANK'
'State <> ''CA'' or State = NULL'
```

Does BLANK mean empty but not null or are they equivalent or are there other differences between these two filters?

Comment: BLANK = Empty String http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=24094&seqNum=8

Comment: @bummi: Excellent. If you enter as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I wonder if TDataSet obeys server rule for `'' IS NULL`...